# placing a layout on top of another

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have searched alot but could not find any working method to achieve this, I have a simple fragment layout. here it is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.gfpishro.signal.FragMalls">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout_error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <include
                layout="@layout/wifi_error_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_mall_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In this layout I have a `recycleview` and a `relativelayout` which includes another layout. it is named `wifi_error_layout` which I call it `error__` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_icon"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_no_connection_24dp_white"
        tools:background="#000000"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_icon"
        tools:text="@string/progressActivityEmptyTitlePlaceholder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5.5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_title"
        tools:text="@string/progressActivityEmptyContentPlaceholder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_retry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/progressActivityErrorButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        style="@style/ButtonOrange"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want them to overlap each other and each time I face an error while loading data into `recycleview` I make `error__` layout visible. but It does not work. I use this function to make it visible and invisible

```
   private void finishUpdate(Boolean status){
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        if(status){
        error__.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            error__.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

but I could not make it work. I tried to use `setZ` but it needs to change `minbuildsdk` and I do not want to do that. I know in Frame layout the order of views indicates the z index but why when I make `error__` layout invisible it does not show `recyleview`. If I change the order of views in xml manually this will work on `recycleview` but the problem occurs on `error__` layout. I mean when I hidden the top view it does not show its bottom view.

Comment: What is the reference of `relative_layout_error`? Is it your error__?

Comment: Could you put an image of your design?

Comment: your question is confusing ... you want to show layout_error only on error loading data other wise it should be invisible right ?

Comment: @Wizard yes it is my error

Comment: @Umair yes this is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @MajidHojati check my answer it will work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is correct, you should put your include outside refresh layout:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_mall_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_error"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <include
        layout="@layout/wifi_error_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: but the problem is when I do not have any thing in recylceview  I can not pull to refresh

Comment: I think if you set your `relative_layout_error` as `wrap_content`, you can pull to refresh.

Comment: How?what do you mean

Comment: thanks it worked but the only problem is with error layout which is located at top left side not in center

Comment: I edited my answer, you just need to set your `layout_gravity` as `center`

Answer (score 1):

Update your following method :

```
private void finishUpdate(Boolean status){
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        if(status){
        error__.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            error__.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Also update fragment with following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.gfpishro.signal.FragMalls">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/wifi_error_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_mall_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your layout like this, also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.gfpishro.signal.FragMalls">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle_mall_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_icon"
                android:layout_width="108dp"
                android:layout_height="108dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_no_connection_24dp_white"
                tools:background="#000000"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_icon"
                tools:text="@string/progressActivityEmptyTitlePlaceholder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="5.5dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_title"
                tools:text="@string/progressActivityEmptyContentPlaceholder" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_retry"
                style="@style/ButtonOrange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/progressActivityErrorButton"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_content" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and also use `View.Gone` instead of `View.Invisible`.

```
 private void finishUpdate(Boolean status){
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    if(status){
    error__.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        error__.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: but now I can not pull to refresh recycleview

Comment: @MajidHojati now which layout doesn't become visible ?